# How to store & access data in one to many relationship of eloquent in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have the following database table structure

```
users table
  id
  mobile
  name

devices
  id 
  user_id
  device
  ip
  active
```

one user can have multiple devices from which user will login

now the question is how to store and access the devices for particular user 
for example, user sam('id',1) has two devices android('user_id',1) and iphone('user_id',1). so when user will come and login i will have mobile no. to get the id of particular user from users table then i will run another query on devices table by user's id which i got from previous query and i have device ralated data.

but i know i am going wrong. what will be the other way .same happened when i am going to store user and related devices. first i store user and then by fetching id i store device for same user.

**this is my User.php model**

```
class User extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['mobile','name'];

   public function device(){

    $this->hasMany('App\Device','tempuser_id');
   }
}
```

**Please tell me how can i deal with this by using eloquent one to many relationship.**

Answer (score 1):

In Model

```
public function devices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Device','user_id', 'id');
}
```

Add device to user

```
$user->devices()->save($device);
```

Get devices

```
foreach($user->devices as $device)
{
     // device here
}
```

Comment: i did this in controller

Comment: public function demo(){

     $user = new user;
     foreach($user->devices as $device)
  {
       return $device;
  }
    }

Comment: and got error "Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation"

Comment: Oh, sorry, model is `return $this->hasMany('App\Device','user_id', 'id');`

Comment: `return` was missed

Comment: I got blank output .

Comment: `public function demo(){ $user = new user; foreach($user->devices as $device) { dd($device); } }`

Comment: still the output is same.

Comment: Whether you have user with related devices in database?

Comment: but i am not passing any id so how will it give me output??

Comment: Change `$user = new user;` to `$user = User::find(1);` if you have user with id=1 in your database

Answer (score 1):

To save devices for a particular user, you can use

```
public function add(Request $request){
  $device= new \App\Device;
  $device->user_id = $request->user()->id;
  $device->device = $request->device;
  $device->ip = $request->ip;
  $device->active =$request->active;
  $devices->save();
}
```

And to retrieve devices for a user, write in your controller

```
$devices = \App\User::find(Auth::user()->id)->devices;
```

Comment: but what if i dont have user's id i have only mobile number of user and on the basis of that i fetch id of particular user. here above you didn't mention any id at the time of saving device.

Comment: First, we don't need to pass id while saving data, since it should has the property of autoincrement. To access the device with the mobile number of user you can use `$devices= \App\User::where('mobile', 'mobile-number')->first()->devices;`

Comment: but user's record is already in users table and i am saving device later for that user. so how do i come to know about id.

Comment: The device id is different from user_id. Each device will have an unique id. And see the third line of the code above, I am storing the id of user, who is currently logged in devices model. This `$request->user()->id;` returns the id of the currently logged in user.

Comment: Thats what i was trying to explain you the id which you are considering is not really that. user will login via mobile no. and otp and at the time of otp verification i am storing user device. so i need to have id of user so that i can store it against device in device table.

Comment: It doesn't matter how your users are logging in. After authenticating the user you can use `$request->user()->id;` or `Auth::user()->id` to retrieve the id of the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126342/discussion-between-sam-and-sunny-kumar).